# Create flat coil

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

I am trying to make a flat coil/helix out of a cylinder like this:

[image]

I have tried playing with the screw modifier but couldn't get anything close to the image.

[image]

Is there a modifier to do this or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5755/599

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A easy way is to use **Extra Objects** addon. And choose *Spirals*. You can get an expected curve with a few tweakings in the left-hand Tool bar. Then use either one of the following four methods to find out the best one for you:

[image]

[image]

Added a **[Demo File](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26898)**.

I personally recommend to use Solidify modifier here, since it is easy to control, and with caps on both ends.

Comment: in OPs illustration there is a gap between each of the rings(S). In your case there is no gap.

Comment: @Vader Gap can be controlled by the **Depth**, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Solidify gives me "faces needed for useful output" could you give instructions on how to use it?

Comment: Never mind, you can ignore that warning in such case. :) Just make sure to define an **Extrude** value in Geometry panel for that curve. However, the Solidify modifier cannot be applied on curve. If you are going to convert the modified result into mesh, just press **Alt C > Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**.

Comment: @Qwertieϟ Did it work for you? Or anything more that I can help?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you will get exactly what you are asking with this method. Maybe close enough.

Use the array modifier.

Start like this. It could also be a cylinder or anything.

[image: start]

Scale it up along the X axis 10%.

Add an array modifier. Uncheck relative offset. Check Object offset. Create an empty and select that as the object to offset.

Rotate the empty 90 degrees around z-axis. Scale it up 10%.

[image: array modifier]

[image: empty transform]

Increase the count in the array modifier.

[image: spiral]

Comment: That last image is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Good. I was thinking that maybe you wanted the width to stay constant. Now it is scaled up 10%^4 for each complete turn.