# How can I make a coil with relief (volute)?

Tags: modeling, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, workflow

I'm trying to model a facade of an arch and I need to create a spiral as shown in these two photos.

[image]

I tried using the addon "Add curve: Extra objects" to create the spiral but  I can not remove the smoothing of vertices. Besides, I'm not sure if I'll have any problems when I change the mesh to adapt the spiral. Note that the figure in the pictures has a relief.

Is this the best way to model the figure?

Note: I'm learning Blender and I followed [these instructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/create-flat-coil).

Comment: I'd like to know how you made this shape in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are probably many different ways to achieve it. I used ***Extra Objects*** and ***F2*** add ons.
[image]

Start with adding a ***Spiral*** (*Add-->Curve-->Spirals*). Play with its settings in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>)
[image]

Convert your *curve* to the *mesh* (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Mesh from Curve*). Then select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>) as pictured below.
[image]

Being in *Edit Mode* add a *Circle* with the equal number as the *Spiral's* ***steps*** number. Extrude the *Circle* and use the *snapping tool* to snap its edge loop to the bottom vertex of a curved mesh. Now use the *knife tool* (press <kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>LMB</kbd>, next <kbd>C</kbd> for a straight cut and then <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through) as pictured below. Delete vertices above and below added cuts.
[image]

Fill the gaps with <kbd>F</kbd> (enable the ***F2*** add on). You may also use the ***bridge tool*** to do it.
[image]

If you want to sharpen edges with edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) retopologize the top part as pictured below. This kind of geometry'll also smooth the end of the curvature.
[image]

Here's my final topology (with no tris and n-gons), that allows me to crease the edges.
[image]

Use ***proportional editing*** with a ***Sharp*** *falloff* type to adjust volute's proportions as you like.
[image]

Comment: It's what I want! I created my model following your detailed tutorial.
Another way might be [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMLQe3HBCGc), with an array. 
I tried it before reading your answer.
However, I think your solution is more accurate. Thanks @Paul Gonet