# How do I create this shape at the top of a violin (the scroll?)

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model a violin, but I am unsure how to make the coiled thingy at the top above the pegs:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74169

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could begin with a *Curve > Curve Spiral > Archemedian* (with the addon *Add Curve: Extra Objects*). Reduce its *Radius Growth*:

[image]

Covert to mesh, extrude down:

[image]

Fill the faces along the spiral:

[image]

Flatten the top on the Z axis:

[image]

Continue to model:

[image]
[image]

Then at one point select all and *Mesh > Symmetrize* on the Z axis:

[image]