Creating a volute
I am hoping to create this object in 3D, it's called a volute in stone-carving. I have the floor plan and sketch attached. Here's a video of the real object
My plan was to use CAD Sketcher addon to map out quadrants from the floor plan. Then use the native knife tool to cut intersections that can be found on the section. I have attached pictures of the floor plan, the section, and the first quadrant, which this plan worked for.
The problem comes when you go to the second quadrant. The tricky thing about this is the inner curvature. Effectively, from the top it spirals around a centre with each quadrant spiralling at different radii, each quadrant also ascends at a different rate, which can be seen from the section.
Finally, as you create this slide-like shape, there exists an internal curve that joins the flat ground to the edges of the shape. I hope I have described this well. I am struggling with the second quadrant as the knife method I described does not account for the internal curve.
I was hoping to just bevel it using the native bevel once I had the general spiralling ascension, but turns out that it leaves a section untouched because of this internal curve. My thinking was that I couldn't use the knife method to trace over that internal curve on the section as this internal curve, also follows the overall spiral curve going round the shape, meaning that the tracing over the curve found on the section would be too straight on and would produce the wrong shape.
The pictures aren't attached in order. I was hoping to show the layout of the drawings. The knife tool cutting example. The case where it does not account for the internal curve of the second quadrant. How the first quadrant looks. And then a closer look at the drawings.






Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46706/how-can-i-make-a-coil-with-relief-volute/46726#46726 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-to-properly-model-the-volute-on-a-capital-of-an-ancient-greek-column

Thanks for the reply
