# Why is this panel grayed out when I add an object? (not sure what it's called)

Tags: modeling

Whenever I add an object this panel is grayed out, does anybody have any clue why this would happen? I'm using factory default everything.
[image: example]

Comment: It's called the operator panel. What add-on's do you have enabled? It seems this is often caused by a bad add-on. Have a look here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36008/75504

Comment: Enable global undo in the preferences.