# Spiral texture/material on the sphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

How to setup material with a texture on the sphere which will look like this

[image: sphere]

I have draw in Paint straight line but I don't know how to bend it spirally around the sphere with material nodes. Also, I don't know how to make transparent background with this line.

[image: l]

Comment: I don't think there is any simple way to do it with this texture. But there is a blender addon that makes spirals. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/model-a-simple-3d-spiral-shape, but change the spiral type in the operator panel

Comment: See this related link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/modelling-a-spiral-around-a-sphere/42165#42165

Comment: Thank you but I don't want the mesh. I want to make spiral texture on the sphere. I thought there is procedural way with the line.  Is it possible to bake mesh spiral onto sphere as a texture?

Answer (score -1):

If the spiral does not have to be mathematically perfect, you can draw it in Tintaur app (iPad/iPhone) and then export textures for use in Blender. It will be a long sequence of linked arcs, start from one pole and add points circularly steadily going towards the opposite pole. After that export the textures (top right button) and replace background color with transparency in some 2D picture editor.[image: A spiral on a sphere]