# Modelling a mechanical spring for a bike

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I am currently modelling a bike based on a Norton 961:

[image]

I struggle with modelling a proper mechanical spring. It should look like this, I think:

[image]

I really don't know how to make it look flowing and natural and having enough "layers".

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post on how to upload images and use that facility please, as great part of your question depends on them and if they go dead so the question with them

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Model a simple 3D spiral shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/model-a-simple-3d-spiral-shape)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Activate the *Add Curve: Curve Extra Objects* addon in the user preferences if you haven't yet.

Then just add a new 3D object with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Curve > Curve Spirals > Logarithmic* or *Archemedian* in you prefer.

Adjust the desired height and number of turns as required.

Adjust curve bevel factor from the *Properties Window > Object Data (Curve)* as desired and set the *Fill* option to *Full*.

[image]

You can then manually add the "flat" end loops manually by joining in a bezier curve circle object afterwards in *Edit Mode*.