# Create a mesh spiral

Tags: mesh

I have cube mesh pole going to the bottom of a icosphere at the moment,
but I also want a mesh spiral going down it too.

I don't want some single vertex line since that wont show up for rendering.

Black line shows what I want, but thicker

[image: Black line is what i want but thicker]

Comment: @cegaton alright i added a image black line is what i want but the gray is what i have rn in blender

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99660/modelling-a-mechanical-spring-for-a-bike/99661#99661

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Add Curve: Extra Objects plugin.

Then do Add->Curve->Cuve Spirals> Archemedean.

Set the height, turns and steps you need.

[image]

To make the curve visible and thicker set the **bevel depth** to whatever you like.

[image]