# Blender 2.79 - Can't find Spiral tools in toolbox

Tags: modeling

This is my first time working with 3D modeling. I thought Blender would be a good one for a beginner. I decided that a necklace would be a good first time project to learn blender.

[image]

However, the necklace has spirals, but I can't find the spiral tools **anywhere** in the tools menu. I've searched for about a half an hour on how to get the spiral tools, but every answer is for an older version of Blender.

[image]

Comment: add curve extras.

Comment: [how to model a spiral shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/model-a-simple-3d-spiral-shape) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=spiral

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely new to Blender, you really should follow a tutorial. I highly recommend [Blender Guru's introductory series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT5oZndzj68&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHs8uzT3yqe4iHGfkCmMJ0P&index=1).

There are a few ways you could approach your problem. The easiest way would be to extrude(select and press e) and rotate(press r and lock it onto an axis by pressing x, y, or z). If you wanted to be more precise, you could use a curve, and taper it with another circle curve. However, this is rather excessive for someone inexperienced. It will take time to get the hang of Blender.